# Visual Studio 2022 Professional Source Control Explorer Stuck in Working

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I have a new laptop.  After installed Visual Studio 2022, the Source Control Explorer worked.  But after I continue to install more other software and deleted some downloaded solution files from TFS, the explorer is stuck in working.  It eventually leads to a frozen Visual Studio with busy message.

Using another laptop with Visual Studio 2022 works.

How to debug and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet right now would be to uninstall Visual Studio and start from scratch.  Depending on what "downloaded solution files" you deleted, something could be seriously messed up with your current installation of VS.

I would do a full re-install and try again.  This may end up saving you time versus troubleshooting.

Comment: I reinstalled the Visual Studio but it still does not work